# load 3D model file (.obj)in native android application in studio

Tags: java, kotlin, android-studio, unity-game-engine, 3d

I have a .obj file which i need to load in native android app. in future in there will be more interaction and elements added arround it.

tried with opengl and few other 3rd party library all came to a dead end.

tried with unity nut unable to generate a android build in it as it is saying build error.